# C++ Operator return difference

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Can anybody explain the difference (if there is any) between the 2 versions of this [] operator?
Both version are working fine ...

```
class Test {

    int arr[100];

    int operator[](int i) {
        return arr[i];
    }

    int & operator[](int i) {
        return arr[i];
    }
};


Test a;
a.arr[5] = 10;

// works for both versions:
int n = a[5];
```

Comment: Why didn't you use the same operator for the assignment of `10`? `Test::arr` is private, after all...

Comment: I don't see how this could work in any version. _Everything_ in the class is private.

Comment: Considering that the code needed for either variant is *very* small, you could easily create two separate [mcve] to showcase each variant. It might have been better.

Comment: ^^, in addition to @Ted 's comment, you can not overload a function for the return type.

Comment: And you should *really* invest in [a couple of good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) to read. Especially the chapters or sections on *references*.

Comment: One returns by value, so `a[5] = n` is not possible, and the other returns by reference, so `a[5] = n` is possible.      However, a class cannot have both versions simultaneously.

Comment: @Peter Not quite true, a class *can* have both variants, if the first one is marked a `const`. As in `int operator[](int i) const;`. The `const`-ness of a member function is part of overload resolution.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - Yes, I know that, but the example given marked neither version with `const` qualifiers, so my comment was directed accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

First, you must make your operators accessible:

```
class Test {
private: 
    int arr[100];

public:
    int operator[](int i) {
        return arr[i];
    }    
    int& operator[](int i) {
        return arr[i];
    }
};
```

Now, this won't compile (since `arr` is private):

```
Test a;
a.arr[5] = 10;
```

`int operator[](int i)` returns by value (an `rvalue`), making `a[5] = 10;` impossible.

`int& operator[](int i)` returns a reference to the `int` stored in `arr` (an `lvalue`) which makes `a[5] = 10;` possible.

But it won't compile since your operators only differ on the return types (`int` vs. `int&`). 
Making the one returning by value `const` solves that issue:

```
#include <iostream>

class Test {
private:
    int arr[100];

public:
    int operator[](size_t i) const { // note the const
        std::cout << "using operator[]() const\n";
        return arr[i];
    }
    int& operator[](size_t i) {
        std::cout << "using operator[]() mutable\n";
        return arr[i];
    }
};

void test_const(const Test& t) {
    std::cout << t[5] << "\n";
}

int main() {
    Test a;
    a[5] = 10;
    std::cout << a[5] << "\n";
    test_const(a);
}
```

Output:

```
using operator[]() mutable
using operator[]() mutable
10
using operator[]() const
10
```

Comment: sorry missleading... the code was meant to be pseudo ... maybe this is more clear

Comment: `class TestA {
        public:
        int arr[100];

        int operator[](int i) {
            return arr[i];
        }
    };

    class TestB {
        public:
        int arr[100];
        int & operator[](int i) {
            return arr[i];
        }
    };


    TestA a;
    a.arr[5] = 10;
    int n = a[5];
    // n is 10

    TestB b;
    b.arr[5] = 10;
    int k = b[5];
    // k is 10`

Comment: @nil_dib In the above you don't have a conflict between the operators since they are in different classes.  You've made `arr` public though which bypasses the operators completely so why even add operators? If your operator returns a reference to a mutable value, you can do `a[5] = 10` but if it returns by value, you can't change the value stored in `arr` via the operator. See the `const`/`mutable` comments in my code.

Comment: basically my question is: what is the difference between these 2 operator implementations 1. int operator[](int i)   2. int & operator[](int i)

Comment: @nil_dib Added explanation for that in the answer. Make `arr` private and it'll be easier to understand too.

Answer (score 0):

First, you must make your operators accessible:

```
class Test {
private: 
    int arr[100];

public:
    int operator[](int i) {
        return arr[i];
    }  // -> Case 1  
    int& operator[](int i) {
        return arr[i];
    } // ->Case 2
};
```

The difference between above two operators is -

Case 1 ->   you can use it only as R value.

Case 2 ->   you can use it as "R value" as well as "L value".